# Pyspark: selecting data in remote Hive Server

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyspark

Trying to read and write data stored in remote Hive Server from Pyspark. I follow this example:

```
from os.path import expanduser, join, abspath

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

# warehouse_location points to the default location for managed databases and tables
warehouse_location = 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse'

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Example shows how to create a new table in warehouse:

```
# spark is an existing SparkSession
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
spark.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'examples/src/main/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")

# Queries are expressed in HiveQL
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM src").show()
```

Yet, I need to access existing tabe `iris` that was created in `mytest.db`, so table location is

```
table_path = warehouse_location + '/mytest.db/iris`
```

How to select from existing table?

**Update**

I have metastore url:

```
http://test.mysite.net:8888/metastore/table/mytest/iris
```

and table location url:

```
hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytest.db/iris
```

when using `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse` as a warehouse location in the code above and trying:

```
spark.sql("use mytest")
```

I get exception:

```
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Database 'mytest' not found;"
```

What would be correct url to select from `iris`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the table directly using

```py
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytest.iris")
```

Or specify the database you want to work with with

```py
spark.sql("use mytest")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM iris)
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see my update to the question. I can not figure out what url to use, please help.